# Having trouble redirecting application output to log file

Tags: stdout, syslog, logger

I have an embedded ARM device running Linux which launches an application on boot.  This application has a bunch of `"printf(...)"` statements in it that I need to view.  The normal way I have been approaching this is to kill the running app through SSH (from a host PC) on the embedded device after it boots, and then re-launch it via the SSH terminal so that I can see the print statements in the console on the host PC.  The problem with this is that the app does not behave well after killing and re-launching it.

What I have attempted to do is edit the startup script to say `"(nohup ./myAppName 2>&1 | logger) &"` and view `/var/log/syslog` with `tail -f`.. however, nothing is getting logged.

I have verified that `"(nohup echo "test123" 2>&1 | logger) &"` does indeed log properly to the syslog.

Where might things be going wrong?  Is it possible that the app is not printing to stdout/stderr?  When I do relaunch the app, it does properly print to the console, but like I said, other things beyond the scope of this are broken when I do so.

Comment: When you "relaunch the app", would it also properly print to a file?

Comment: I have no tried relaunching and printing to file, but it would print to console just fine..  I am working on implementing your strace answer below and will post results soon

Comment: If you already use nohup - why don't you just use the nohup.out file it generates, like described in the man page?

Comment: Jaleks I've tried this but nohup.out is blank... the program may not be as verbose if stdout is not a tty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some program are less verbose when stdout is not a tty. You can emulate a tty using screen:

```
screen -L -d -m ./myAppName
```

which logs the output to something like `./screenlog.0`. You need write permission in the current directory!

Otherwise it's also possible that the program simply fails silently only within your boot environment.

I would debug that using `strace` and avoiding `logger`:

```
strace -f -o /tmp/myApp.strace nohup ./myAppName >/tmp/myApp.log 2>&1
```

Comment: myApp.log shows "nohup: ignoring input" and the .strace file is huge, lots of messages that I have to sort through.

I think you are on to something when you say "less verbose when stdout is not a tty" how can I change that?  Thanks again

Comment: I've edited the answer regarding tty emulation. And yes, the strace log  might be difficult to read for non-programmers. Maybe you see at the and why the program exists.

Comment: I don't have the screen command available D:, any other way?

Comment: Can't you install screen? Otherwise you could post your strace output on http://pastebin.com/ if it does not contain private secrets.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can install screen on this ARM device, nor post the strace because it does have some sensitive information in it :<  I think I am close, thank you for your tips